# How to return a HashTable from a WebService?

Tags: c#, web-services

My webservice is returning all string variables. Now I want to modify my service so that it can return HashTable object. This is the signature of my WebService entry-point(method):

```
public void getPrevAttempts(string fbUserId, string studentId, string assessmentId, out string isAuthenticated, out HashTable attempts)
```

The records in the HashTable are inserted form the result of an SQL query. Whenever I'm tryimg to run my service, I'm getting redirected to accessdenied.htm page(Since my Web.config has this entry `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="accessdenied.htm"/>`). Is there any way to return `HashTable` or the result of SQL query?

## Update:

Exception:`The type System.Collections.Hashtable is not supported because it implements IDictionary.`

Comment: what is the error return by service?

Comment: `HashTable`, the 90's again...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `out` parameters aren't supported in a web service signature. You also may run into serialization problems, especially across platforms (a string is a universally known type, but a .Net Hashtable is not). However, a Hashtable *is* marked as serializable, so the first thing I would try is using it as the return value.

Comment: You can return `DataSet` or `DataTable`

Comment: @Tim Medora: `out` parameters are supported. Whether they should be used by a web service method is a different matter.

Comment: You should not be using a `Hashtable` in your web service method signature. It's a complex type and would not be interoperable with non-.NET platforms. Consider refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize the data to JSON string and return to the client.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
HashTable ht = New HashTable();
//Populate ht.
response = serializer.Serialize(ht) // This will serialize the data to JSON format.
```

On the Client side, de-serialize using

```
httpResponse = JSON.parse(response); //httpResponse will have key value pair data as you created in server.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create your own custom object or create an array.
You can than convert it back to a HashTable.
The use of out parameters is also not a good idea.
It's better to create a custom class with IsAuthenticated and Attempts as properties.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily convert the `HashTable` to a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` and return that...

Instead of returning the data structure, think of returning the data - and rebuilding the data structure on the client side.