# How to convert a multi dimensional array into json format in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have created a multidimenssional array.. which stores multiple rows from my database table..

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select  * from question_bank_details  where question_num  in (select top 2 question_num  from question_bank_details order by newid())", con5);
 DataTable data_table = new DataTable();
 DataList data_list = new DataList();
 da.Fill(data_table);

 string[,] array_questions = new string[dt.Rows.Count,dt.Columns.Count];

 for (int i = 0; i <dt.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
      for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
      {
           array_questions[i, j] = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();

      }
 }
 data_list.DataSource = data_table;
 data_list.DataBind();
```

now I need to convert this multi dimenssional array into JSON format.please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = js.Serialize(array_questions);
```

Source :[How do I convert a c# two-dimensional array to a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291076/how-do-i-convert-a-c-sharp-two-dimensional-array-to-a-json-object)

Comment: thankyou..but when sending the data, it is received as a very long single line ..how can i transfer it row wise?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Json.NET 4.0](http://json.codeplex.com/), It is also available in Nuget

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array_questions);
```

Comment: I just used JSON.NET for dotnet 4.0 for my project, and I can say it worked -perfectly- I suggest this answer.

Answer (score 0):

this example is basically converting javascript to json....hope you might get some idea   from this
you need to use an open-source json parser and stringfier check at http://www.json.org/

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js
after then you have to include the code and use the JSON.stringify() method on your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(array_questions); // This will serialize array to JSON string.
```

If you want to deserialize from JScript, use

```
JSON.Parse(array_questions);
```

Please refer this one also for JScript deserilazation 
[How to return a HashTable from a WebService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829465/how-to-return-a-hashtable-from-a-webservice/16830501#16830501)